# Custom view with data source. When should the data source be queried for the first time?

Tags: ios, uiview

I am making a custom `UIView` that has a datasource much like a `UITableView`. When should this datasource be asked for data for the first time and in which method of my `UIView` subclass?

Right now I query the datasource when it is set in my view's property.

I'm thinking that the table view does this differently, because if I provide it's datasource in a storyboard/xib and I create the data in the `viewDidLoad` method of the view controller (by then the datasource is already set) then the datasource will still be queried without calling `reloadData`. When does a table view reload it's data without asking it explicitly to do so?

Answer (score 2):

I had a hunch, but to get an authoritative answer, I used the debugger. I set a break point in `-numberOfSectionsInTableView:` and `-tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`.

They are called from `-[UITableView reloadData]` of course, but also from `-[UITableView layoutSubviews]`. In the special case of `-[UITableViewController tableView]`, `-[UITableViewController viewWillAppear:]` calls `-numberOfSectionsInTableView:` directly (iOS 6.1 simulator).